# lambdalatex's tex live installation can't work with cyrillic

Tags: texlive, input-encodings, latexmk, compilation-error, cyrillic

Latexmk fails to compile my document with cyrillic symbols.

**Terminal output:**

```shell
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 6 Nov. 2023. Version 4.81.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "document.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /tmp/latex/) to root's actual home (/root).
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /tmp/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: --- remaking pdflatex with pdftex
mktexfmt: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdflatex -progname=pdflatex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdflatex.ini' ...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 (/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/cp227.tcx)
entering extended mode
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-ini-files/pdflatex.ini
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg)
./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers, parameters,
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01>
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.ltx
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)) hacks,
document commands, control, par, spacing, files, font encodings, lengths,
====================================

Local config file fonttext.cfg used

====================================
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonttext.cfg
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonttext.ltx
=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===

(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlenc.def)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.def)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.def)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmr.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmss.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmtt.fd)))
====================================

Local config file fontmath.cfg used

====================================
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.cfg
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx
=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===

(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmsy.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omxcmex.fd)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ucmr.fd)))
====================================

Local config file preload.cfg used

=====================================
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.cfg
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.ltx)) page nos.,
x-ref, environments, center, verbatim, math definitions, boxes, title,
sectioning, contents, floats, footnotes, index, bibliography, output,
===========================================
Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used
===========================================
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/hyphen.cfg
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/dumyhyph.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/zerohyph.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/zerohyph.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/zerohyph.tex))
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu))
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/firstaid/latex2e-first-aid-for-exte
rnal-files.ltx)
 ) )
Beginning to dump on file pdflatex.fmt
 (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.23)
23773 strings of total length 453446
1922741 memory locations dumped; current usage is 204&365374
22061 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\c__fp_exp_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00002pt
\font\c__fp_trig_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00003pt
\font\c_initex_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00005pt
\font\c_other_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00006pt
\font\c_str_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00008pt
\font\g_tmpa_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00009pt
\font\g_tmpb_cctab=cmr10 at 0.0001pt
\font\g__regex_state_active_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00012pt
\font\g__regex_thread_info_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00014pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_prev_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00015pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_begin_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00017pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_end_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00018pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_case_intarray=cmr10 at 0.0002pt
\font\g__regex_balance_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00021pt
\font\g__codepoint_category_index_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00023pt
\font\g__codepoint_uppercase_index_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00024pt
\font\g__codepoint_lowercase_index_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00026pt
\font\g__codepoint_category_blocks_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00027pt
\font\g__codepoint_uppercase_blocks_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00029pt
\font\g__codepoint_lowercase_blocks_intarray=cmr10 at 0.0003pt
\font\OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10
\font\tenln=line10
\font\tenlnw=linew10
\font\tencirc=lcircle10
\font\tencircw=lcirclew10
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/5=cmr5
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/7=cmr7
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/10=cmr10
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/5=cmmi5
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/7=cmmi7
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/10=cmmi10
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/5=cmsy5
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/7=cmsy7
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10=cmsy10
\font\c_code_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00032pt
\font\c_document_cctab=cmr10 at 0.00034pt
558062 words of font info for 36 preloaded fonts
14 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 6081 has 183 ops out of 35111
  2 for language 1
  181 for language 0
0 words of pdfTeX memory
0 indirect objects
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pdflatex.log.
mktexfmt [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
mktexfmt [INFO]: /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
mktexfmt [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 1
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 10
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 11
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
entering extended mode

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 tcti1728

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt mf.base
mktexfmt [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /tmp/latex/) to root's actual home (/root).
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /tmp/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: --- remaking mf with mf-nowin
mktexfmt: running `mf-nowin -ini   -jobname=mf -progname=mf -translate-file=cp227.tcx mf.ini' ...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (INIMF)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/cp227.tcx)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/metafont/config/mf.ini
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/metafont/base/plain.mf
Preloading the plain base, version 2.71: preliminaries,
 basic constants and mathematical macros,
 macros for converting from device-independent units to pixels,
 macros and tables for various modes of operation,
 macros for drawing and filling,
 macros for proof labels and rules,
 macros for character and font administration,
and a few last-minute items.)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/modes/modes.mf) )
Beginning to dump on file mf.base
 (preloaded base=mf 2023.11.23)
2237 strings of total length 30230
11955 memory locations dumped; current usage is 3679&7916
1011 symbolic tokens
Transcript written on mf.log.
mktexfmt [INFO]: log file copied to: /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c/metafont/mf.log
mktexfmt [INFO]: /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c/metafont/mf.base installed.
mktexfmt [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 1
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 10
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 11
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
mktexpk: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1+0/600; nonstopmode; input tcti1728
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)

(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcti1728.mf
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exbase.mf)
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcti.mf
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txsymb.mf
 Ok (/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/exaccess.mf
 Ok) (/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txpseudo.mf
 Ok) (/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txaccent.mf
 Ok [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [27] [29])
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txgen.mf
 Ok [100] [109] [98] [99] [108])
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txsymbol.mf
 Ok [13] [18] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [28] [31] [32] [36] [39] [44]
[45] [46] [42] [47] [60] [61] [62] [77] [79] [87] [110] [91] [93] [94] [95]
[96] [126] [127] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136] [137]
[138] [139] [140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149]
[150] [151] [152] [153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161]
[162] [163] [164] [165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [171] [172] [173] [174]
[175] [177] [176] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [187] [191] [214] [246])
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txitlod.mf
 Ok [48] [49] [53] [54] [56] [57] [50] [51] [52] [55])
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txisuper.mf
 Ok [185] [178] [179] [170] [186])
(/var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/txifract.mf
 Ok [188] [189] [190]) ) ) )
(some charht values had to be adjusted by as much as 0.10785pt)
Font metrics written on tcti1728.tfm.
Output written on tcti1728.600gf (128 characters, 40228 bytes).
Transcript written on tcti1728.log.
mktexpk: /tmp/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcti1728.600pk: successfully generated.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'document.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'document.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'document.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'document.pdf'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  document.aux

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "document.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: ====List of undefined refs and citations:
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character Л (U+041B)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ь (U+044C)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character в (U+0432)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character і (U+0456)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character в (U+0432)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character с (U+0441)
  ! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ь (U+044C)
 And 279 more --- see log file.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'document.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'document.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'document.log'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'document.pdf'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  =====Latex reported missing or unavailable character(s).
=====See log file for details.
Latexmk: Errors, in force_mode: so I tried finishing targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'document.log' and/or above output for details
```

**Part of document.tex**

```tex
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\date{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\title{Звіт}

\begin{document}
\section{Вступ}
\subsection{Завдання}
визначити критичну температуру ефіру.

\end{document}
```

#### Update 1

Added full document so others can test it.
Also i'll add some context:

I'm running latexmk on docker image of AWS Lambda runtime environment.
To reduce size of installation, texlive profile was modified:
**texlive.profile**

```
selected_scheme scheme-custom
TEXDIR /var/tex/texlive/2017
TEXMFCONFIG /tmp/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME /tmp/texmf
TEXMFLOCAL /var/tex/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /var/tex/texlive/2017/texmf-var
TEXMFVAR /tmp/texmf-var
binary_x86_64-linux 1
collection-basic 1
collection-latex 1
instopt_adjustpath 0
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 0
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 0
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 0
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 0
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
```

Also `luatex` package was forcely removed.

this `\VAR{something}` it isn't tex's directives. Before actual compilation external template engine replaces these with plain text. Template engine was modified to work with `\VAR{}` syntax to not break syntax analyzer of app i'm coding in.

Also this is texlive 2023 installed in 2017's directory. It's because texlive profile and all other latex things has taken from [lambdalatex](https://github.com/samoconnor/lambdalatex).

#### Update 2

Modified my document to remove all unnecessary stuff. Also i can't add full document.log to this question due to symbol limit of stackexchange, so I uploaded it to pastebin [HERE](https://pastebin.com/5FAS1PKR). Updated terminal output for new file.

#### Update 3

Removed `\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}` line that was probably causing `Encoding file t2aenc.def not found.`. And uploaded new [document.log](https://pastebin.com/jZ1s8yw1). But this t2aenc.def error not gone

#### Update 4

Added `cyrillic` package to my installation. Still no compiling pdf.
Linked new [log](https://pastebin.com/wFSV5Qvc). And it became even worse, i cant get terminal output - it crashes.

#### Update 5

Installed `babel-ukrainian`. This still doesn't wors but [errors in log changed](https://pastebin.com/1dxTjrea). Also latexmk still crashes terminal.

#### Solution

Due to the peculiarities of how I installed tex live, most of the packages needed to work with Cyrillic were not installed. Thanks to samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and cfr, it became clear that some packages needed to be added to the standard lambdalatex installation to make Cyrillic work.

- cyrillic
- babel-ukrainian
- cm-super
- ukrhyph

Comment: That has nothing to do with latexmk, you get the same result with `pdflatex` as the log shows. You might want to update the title of your question. Please extend your example to a full document testable by others.

Comment: Also you might want to replace the log you showed with the actual contents of the generated log file as that your be more relevant whan the termianl outout friom latexmk

Comment: your format is created with files from texlive 2017, but your pdftex claims to be from texlive 2023. You should sort your tex systems. And check if you have the cyrillic support installed.

Comment: Why are you setting `TEXDIR /var/tex/texlive/2017` etc. if you use texlive 2023?

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, To avoid breaking compatibility with the rest of the lambdalatex code

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for chaos! Can you guarantee that there aren't any leftovers from texlive 2017?

Comment: your document can't be tested. It uses undefined commands, local images and errors. Make a better (and shorter) example and then show its log-file.

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Unfortunately, this is true, but I have to work with this pile of old code. I am quite sure that there are no remnants of the 2017 version, because it was never installed. From the very beginning, the 2023 version was in the 2017 folder

Comment: The first error in your log file is `! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file t2aenc.def not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
` Fix this first before looking at any other errors

Comment: There is no mention of `t2aenc.def` in my document. Do I need to look elsewhere besides the content of my document?
NEW: Oh sorry i understood that it's about font encoding. I'll try to remove it and update question

Comment: @Ig.Foer You seem to have an incomplete texlive installation, that's why the file is missing. How did you install texlive? Via your linux package manger or the vanilla version from tug.org?

Comment: you need t2aenc for cyrillic. And as I wrote: check if you have the cyrillic support installed.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've installed texlive manually (downloaded installer from `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz`). Also after installation some stps were followed:
removed `texmf-dist/doc `, `texmf-dist/source/latex/koma-script/doc`, `tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb*`
Also manually added `perl-Digest-MD5` to installation

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to check if Cyrillic support is installed. Do I need to install some additional package to support Cyrillic?

Comment: @Ig.Foer What does `tlmgr info cyrillic` say?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Whol output can't fit into this comment, bit it seems thai it is not installed. I'll try to fix it and update question

Comment: @Ig.Foer Then install it with `tlmgr install cyrillic`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz `cyrillic` is now installed but it still now working. Also, what is difference between `cyrillic` and `texlive-lang-cyrillic`. Maybe I should install 2 of these packages at once?

Comment: `texlive-lang-cyrillic` sounds like something from a linux packaged texlive

Comment: The next missing package is `babel-ukrainian`. Why don't you just install a complete texlive and avoid all these missing packages?

Comment: Off-topic: If you don't use `\chapter` you should switch from class `report` to `article` instead of using`\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`. If you want a title page, just use option `titlepage`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I need to keep my texlive installation as small as possible due to AWS lambda limit of 50mb.

Comment: You have to install fonts and font support files which actually support Ukrainian. In addition, you're missing hyphenation rules and it's using English, which will give poor results. It's looking for cm-super, but you could use something else provided you tell it. There's nothing wrong with your document's source. It's all about your installation.

Comment: Install at least `ukrhyph` and `cm-super`.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to install fonts, for example `cm-super`. Is it tlmgr package or something external?

Comment: @Ig.Foer `tlmgr install cm-super`.

Comment: Instead of editing in "Solution", you should post it as an answer (or accept that the question samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz pointed to is a duplicate of your question).